# How to avoid null safety validation?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I just upgraded my Dart and Flutter Version and my project is a mess. Even I tried to downgrade and also return to my "stable" and "master" channel instead of the "beta" one.

Is there a way to skip all these validation at least for a while? I cannot even run my project :P

Thanks in Advance

[Dart Analysis Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw93Q.png)

Comment: Change your min sdk level in pubspec.  This is detailed in the pages on dart.dev and flutter.dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Terminal on Mac or CommandLine on Window and try this script:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub get
```

Rebuild the project again

If It does not work update Flutter to Channel Stable

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade --force
```

Also, run `flutter doctor` and fix all the issues

Answer (score 0):

**https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety**

**Disable sound null safety using the `--no-sound-null-safety` flag to the dart or flutter command:**

**In Dart :**

```
 dart --no-sound-null-safety run
```

**with flutter**

```
 flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```